# Real World Async and Await Code Example

Tags: c#, async-await

I have been looking everywhere to find good real world examples of the new Async and Await features in .net 4.5. I have come up with the following code to download a list of files and limit the number of concurrent downloads. I would appreciate any best practices or ways to improve/optimize this code.

We are calling the below code using the following statement.

```
await this.asyncDownloadManager.DownloadFiles(this.applicationShellViewModel.StartupAudioFiles, this.applicationShellViewModel.SecurityCookie, securityCookieDomain).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

We are then using events to add the downloaded files to an observablecollection (new thread safe version in .net 4.5)  on the ViewModel.

```
public class AsyncDownloadManager
    {
        public event EventHandler<DownloadedEventArgs> FileDownloaded;

        public async Task DownloadFiles(string[] fileIds, string securityCookieString, string securityCookieDomain)
          {
            List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>();
            //Limits Concurrent Downloads 
            SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: Properties.Settings.Default.maxConcurrentDownloads);

            var urls = CreateUrls(fileIds);

            foreach (var url in urls)   
            {  
                await throttler.WaitAsync();
                allTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () => 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(securityCookieString))
                        {
                            Cookie securityCookie;
                            securityCookie = new Cookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, securityCookieString);
                            securityCookie.Domain = securityCookieDomain;
                            httpClientHandler.CookieContainer.Add(securityCookie);    
                        }                     

                        await DownloadFile(url, httpClientHandler).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        throttler.Release();
                    }
                }));
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(allTasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        async Task DownloadFile(string url, HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
            DownloadedFile downloadedFile = new DownloadedFile();

            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
                var byteArray = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                if (responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition != null)
                {
                    downloadedFile.FileName = Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.workingDirectory, responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (!Directory.Exists(Properties.Settings.Default.workingDirectory))   
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Properties.Settings.Default.workingDirectory);
                }
                using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(downloadedFile.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true))
                {
                    await filestream.WriteAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {    
                return; 
            }
            OnFileDownloaded(downloadedFile);
        }

        private void OnFileDownloaded(DownloadedFile downloadedFile)
        {    
            if (this.FileDownloaded != null)
            {
                this.FileDownloaded(this, new DownloadedEventArgs(downloadedFile));
            }
        }    

    public class DownloadedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public DownloadedEventArgs(DownloadedFile downloadedFile)
        {   
            DownloadedFile = downloadedFile;
        }

        public DownloadedFile DownloadedFile { get; set; }
    }
```

After suggestion by Svick - The following are direct questions:

1. What is the affect of embedding Async / Await in other Async / Await methods? (Write filestream to disk inside an Async / Await method.
2. Should a httpclient be used for each separate task or should they share a singe one?
3. Are events a good way to "send" the downloaded file reference to the viewmodel?
   [I will also post in codereview]

Comment: I don't see any real question in your post, so I think it's not on topic here. Maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better choice.

Comment: Now reposted as http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18519/real-world-async-and-await-code-example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your questions are not directly related to your code, so I will answer them here:

> What is the effect of embedding Async / Await in other Async / Await methods? (Write filestream to disk inside an Async / Await method.)

`async` methods are meant to be combined like this. Actually that's the only thing `async`-`await` can be used to: combine asynchronous methods to create another asynchronous method.

What happens is that if you `await` a `Task` that is not finished yet, your method actually returns to the caller. Then, when the `Task` completes, your method is resumed on the original context (for example the UI thread in UI application).

If you don't want to continue on the original context (because you don't need it), you can change that by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, like you already do. There is no need to do this inside `Task.Run()`, because that code doesn't run in the original context.

> Should a httpclient be used for each separate task or should they share a singe one?

The documentation of `HttpClient` says that its instance methods are not thread-safe, so you should use separate instance for each `Task`.

> Are events a good way to "send" the downloaded file reference to the viewmodel?

I think events don't fit well together with `async`-`await`. In your case, it would work only if you used [`BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh198845.aspx) and were also properly locking the collection in your own code.

I think a better alternative would be to use something like TPL Dataflow or Rx.

Answer (score 2):

If you embed async await you should use

```
Task.ConfigureAwait(false)
```

on anything that returns a Task otherwise the task will continue on the thread context of the caller which is unnecessary except on the UI thread. In summary, libaries should use ConfigureAwait(false) and UI code should not. That is about it!